# How to unpause during a multiplayer game?

Tags: starcraft-2

I was just stuck in a multiplayer Starcraft 2 game for 10 minutes, because I didn't know how to unpause the game!

So please, fellow gamers, help me and other newbies out and explain us how to unpause the game!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the menu (F10) and click on "Resume" to unpause the game. The click "Return to Game" to close the menu and keep on playing.

Comment: Don't click "Surrender!" by accident. xD

Comment: I seriously had to Google this, so thanks! You get my accept if you add a picture ;-)

Comment: You can also push the pause button on your keyboard.